# Why do some Elixir library functions use multiple arities, while others use default values?

Tags: elixir, default-arguments, arity

As an example, the `Integer.parse/2` function has a default value of 10 for base, whereas `String.to_integer/1` and `String.to_integer/2` both exist, where the second is used for when `base` needs to be specified.

Is there any reason that it was implemented this way?
When should I use one or the other to define functions?

My assumed answer is that there is some actual difference in implementation for the differing arities, whereas the default value version shares the same implementation. However, I don't know why there would be a different implementation in this case, specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly the same thing under the covers. When you specify a default argument in Elixir, what happens is that two functions get created. One of one arity less with the arg set to the default and one that takes the 
additional arg. As you can see by introspecting the Integer module, it 
exports parse/1 and parse/2.

```
iex(2)> Integer.module_info(:exports)
[__info__: 1, digits: 1, digits: 2, floor_div: 2, "MACRO-is_even": 2,
 "MACRO-is_odd": 2, mod: 2, parse: 1, parse: 2, to_char_list: 1, to_charlist: 1,
 to_charlist: 2, to_string: 1, to_string: 2, undigits: 1, undigits: 2,
 module_info: 0, module_info: 1 ]
```

In the case of `String.to_integer` the authors decided to be more explict and reflect the wrapping of underlying Erlang functions that implement this.

Comment: Wow. First, it is cool to see that aspect of default arguments, but secondly, it makes more sense that they would do it that way to align with the Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

[Functions accepting default arguments are transformed into multiple functions with corresponding arities](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3593).

In my view, the practice persists because functions written using multiple function heads to accommodate default arguments permit writing more intelligible guard clauses than `//`-style default parameters.

Additionally, because functions defined with multiple heads are pervasive in Erlang (which a good deal of Elixir code is written with reference to) straightforward translation preserves a disproportionate amount of code without `//`.